# Apache to Tomcat forward all except webmail folder with mod_jk

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, tomcat6, mod-jk

I have setup `apache` and `tomcat6` and forward all requests to tomcat with `mod_jk`.

I want all url for a specific virtualhost to be forwarded to tomcat except for the webmail folder that should be handled by apache.

Currently I am using the JkMount /* worker1 directive in the httpd.conf

Please suggest how I could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

With many trials & errors, I finaly got it to work.

For anyone interested here is what I have done in the **httpd.conf** file

```
JkOptions  +ForwardURICompatUnparsed
JkMount /* worker1
JkUnmount /webmail/* worker1
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/webmail/ [R]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I was looking for this exactly!